# Is it possible to compress an atom to infinite density?

Tags: particle-physics, black-holes, pressure, atomic-physics

I am asking this question because I always wonder what would happen if we had a machine or something that could compress an element to infinite density. This question has been on my mind since I was in 11th grade. Although I quit my study after 12th grade? But still, sometimes it comes to my mind and I start thinking about it. And then more questions come up, like what are the benefits of achieving this theoretically? Is it possible to do that? And what would happen if we did it? I mean, what are the pros and cons of it? How can we do that?

Answer (score 1):

We can see what happens when we try and compress atoms by considering stars.

While star is shining, some of the atoms (strictly speaking the nuclei) are being fused together, releasing energy which we see (eventually) as light.  So even before the star "dies" it is converting nuclei to different nuclei.  Indeed, almost all the atoms in your body that are not hydrogen were made this way.  This energy also keeps the star "alive" and prevents it's gravitational collapse (by keeping it hot and hence producing a counter-balancing pressure).

In broad terms, when a star stops being able to support it's own mass (weight) using fusion, we get left with an object that wants to collapse in on itself due to it's own gravitational force on itself.

The first thing that happens is that a [white dwarf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_dwarf) is created.  This is a result of the electrons being forced so close together than an effect (only explained by quantum theory) prevents them from getting any closer.

When we get to this level of density, (electron degenerate matter in a white dwarf), we've essentially stopped talking about atoms as we would think of them in everyday physics.

However if there is enough mass in the star as a whole, even this extreme effect is not enough to prevent further collapse.  A large enough star will collapse and form a [neutron star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_star).  A neutron star is prevented from collapsing further (unless it's large enough) by yet another effect in quantum theory.

At this point the material inside is thought to be something called quark-gluon soup.  Even the nuclei of our atom are no longer identifiable to us - they're part of a "mush" of quarks.

If the star is large enough it will be able to collapse into an even more dense state and can become a black hole.  Now, black holes are quite odd in any number of ways, one of which is that they don't get smaller (at least in any meaningful way).  Once they form, that's the smallest they'll get.  There's also no meaning to density here, because what happens inside the event horizon is, by definition, something we don't see from the outside.

The density of a black hole has no practical meaning, because everything inside the event horizon appears, from the outside, to act as if it was at the singularity.  That doesn't mean it's infinitely dense, it means it has no meaning to talk about density.

So you can think of the white dwarf upper limit as a maximum density before you inevitably get a neutron star.  The upper limit for neutron star mass related to the maximum density before you get a black hole.  At that point, when something becomes a black hole, density doesn't have any practical meaning.  You don't really get infinite density and the concept of density stops having relevance.  People do sometimes say that a singularity has infinite density, but it's not a useful way to think about it.

But long before we reached the black hole stage, there ceased to be anything identifiable as an atom, and certainly not the atoms we started with.